# Password questions

Tags: feature-request

Noticing yet another password question this morning, albeit an old one, made me think that perhaps it would be worthwhile having the system place an automatic protection lock on all questions that have the word "password" the the title. The purpose being to cut down on the password cracking spam we get.

I realise of course that would include a vast number of questions that aren't actually concerned with password cracking or resetting but will that really matter? Worst case it would prevent new members answering those questions but from what I've seen so far that would have absolutely minimal effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think we don't need this. This would make it more difficult for new users to start using the site. When we see such questions, flag them for 'Protection'. That should be enough.